# How to sort an array randomly without any two adjacent values being the same?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

**I have a regex from PHP which I need to convert to JavaScript.**

Basically, I have an array [A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,...,A,B,C]

This array get's shuffled in a random order and then I need to sort the array so that none of two following values are the same.

This is the function in PHP:

```
function shuffleTracks($array) {
    shuffle($array);
    $string = implode(' ',$array);
    
    foreach(array_unique($array) as $v) {
        $pullcount = $pushcount1 = $pushcount2 = 0;
        $string = preg_replace("/$v (?=$v)/","",$string,-1,$pullcount);  // remove the first value of each conflicting pair
        $string = preg_replace("/ \K(?<!$v )(?!$v)|^(?!$v)/","$v ",$string,$pullcount,$pushcount1);  // foreach removal, re-insert value(s) where valid
        if($pullcount <= $pushcount1) {
            $string = preg_replace("/$(?<!$v)/"," $v",$string,$pullcount-$pushcount1,$pushcount2);
        }
        if($pullcount != $pushcount1 + $pushcount2) {
            $error = "Failure while replacing $v $pullcount & ".$pushcount1 + $pushcount2."\n";
            echo $error;
            break;
        }
    }
    $array = explode(" ",$string);
    return $array;
}

$array = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C'];

$array = shuffleArray($array);
```

This is what I have so far in JavaScript (I recreated the preg_replace function to JS);

```js
function preg_replace(object) {

    var pattern, replacement, subject, limit, count, output;

    (object.hasOwnProperty('pattern')) ? pattern = object.pattern : console.log('error');
    (object.hasOwnProperty('replacement')) ? replacement = object.replacement : console.log('error');
    (object.hasOwnProperty('subject')) ? subject = object.subject : console.log('error');
    (object.hasOwnProperty('limit')) ? limit = object.limit : limit = -1;
    (object.hasOwnProperty('count')) ? count = object.count : count = null;

    if (limit == -1) {
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
        subject = subject.replace(regex, () => {
            count++;
            return replacement
        });
    } else {
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            subject = subject.replace(regex, () => {
                count++;
                return replacement;
            })
        }
    }

    (count != null) ? output = { subject, count } : output = { subject }
    return output
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    const shuffle = (array) => {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            const temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    shuffle(array);

    let string = array.join(' ');
    let unique = [...new Set(array)];

    unique.forEach((v) => {
        var pullcount = 0,
            pushcount1 = 0,
            pushcount2 = 0;

        object = preg_replace({ pattern: `${v} (?=${v})`, replacement: ``, subject: string, limit: -1, count: pullcount });                            // remove the first value of each conflicting pair
        pullcount = object.count;
        string = object.subject;

        object = preg_replace({ pattern: `\K(?<!${v} )(?!${v})|^(?!${v})`, replacement: `${v} `, subject: string, limit: pullcount, count: pushcount1 }); // foreach removal, re-insert value(s) where valid
        pushcount1 = object.count;
        string = object.subject;

        if (pullcount <= pushcount1) {
            object = preg_replace({ pattern: `$(?<!${v})`, replacement: ` ${v}`, subject: string, limit: pullcount - pushcount1, count: pushcount2 });
            pushcount2 = object.count;
            string = object.subject;
        }
        if (pullcount != (pushcount1 + pushcount2)) {
            // console.log(`Failure while replacing ${v} ${pullcount} & ${pushcount1 + pushcount2} \n`);
            return;
        }
    })
    array = string.split(' ');
    return array;

}

var array = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C'];


console.log(array.join(" "));
console.log(array.length);
array = shuffleArray(array);
console.log(array.join(" "));
console.log(array.length);
```

However, the \K parameter doesn't exist in JavaScript and thus my array isn't getting shuffled correctly...

```
object = preg_replace({ pattern: `\K(?<!${v} )(?!${v})|^(?!${v})`, replacement: `${v} `, subject: string, limit: pullcount, count: pushcount1 });
```

Mainly, the double occurences get stripped out of the string but are not placed back, resulting in a new array that is not of equal length anymore.
Please help.

Comment: Could you please explain how are you shuffling the array in php (what do the regexes do, what is \K)?

Comment: In PHP after the shuffle($array) the A,B,C's are all mixed and therefor two or more concurrent values in the array can be the same [A,A,B,B,B,C,A,C,C] for example.

The first regex replaces all the values that are next to each other with "" and counts the occurences.

The second regex reinserts the stripped values back in positions where this is possible, using the limit from the previous count.

Comment: (1) I'm thoroughly unconvinced that your algorithm is truly "random". Some results will be much more likely than others. (2) For some inputs, no algorithm exists. (3) For some inputs, an algorithm does exist, but your algorithm would fail.

Comment: (1) Then you would argue that shuffle() is also not truly random. (2/3) Please point me in the direction of an already existing algorithm for JavaScript that does what I needed it to do?

Comment: Ofcourse, an input array of AAAAAB would not work, obviously.

Comment: (4) What are your input array constraints? Do you always have same the amount of each letter? (5) If yes, have you considered (re)generating the array randomly instead of shuffling it? (6) This algorithm seems to me to be of complexity O(n^2), so it is not suitable for very large arrays (it would take too long). OTOH I'm not sure whether it could be done quicker. (1) The result is not random, (at least) because `preg_replace` replaces first n occurences, not random n.

Comment: (4) The array is always built up by a repeating pattern, ending on whichever value comes last. Other arrays MAY work but are not guaranteed (e.g. AAAAB will fail, AACBA will succeed). I can not generate the array randomly, no two values may be adjacent. (5) I am not sure, I tried on array sizes of 500+ and it seems pretty quick. (1) But the position of the first occurences where the value can be returned depends on the randomizing shuffle function. You can rerun the function, it will always give a different result. Also, see my JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Any array that has a solution can be randomly sorted without any two adjacent values being the same.**

I wrote the equivalent regexp above each part which does what.

```js
// First a simple shuffle function
function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}

function shuffleSort(array) {

    let unique = [...new Set(array)];

    unique.forEach((v) => {

        var pullcount = 0,
            pushcount1 = 0,
            pushcount2 = 0;

        // regExp(/${v} (?=${v})/, "g")
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ((array[i] == v) && (array[i+1] == v)) {         // "${v} (?=${v})"
                array.splice(i, 1)
                pullcount++;
                i--;
            }
        }

        // regExp(/ \K(?<!${v} )(?!${v})|^(?!${v})/)
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[0] != v) {                                // "|^(?!${v})"
                array.splice(0, 0, v);
                pushcount1++;
            }
            if ((array[i] != v) && (array[i-1] != v)) {         // " \K(?<!${v} )(?!${v})"
                array.splice(i, 0, v);
                pushcount1++;
            }
            if (pushcount1 >= pullcount) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // regExp(/$(?<!${v})/)
        if (pullcount <= pushcount1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pullcount - pushcount1; i++) {
                if (array[array.length - 1] != v) {             // "$(?<!${v})"
                    array.push(v);
                    pushcount2++;
                }
            }

        }

        if (pullcount != (pushcount1 + pushcount2)) {
            console.log(`Failure while replacing ${v} ${pullcount} & ${pushcount1 + pushcount2} \n`);
        }
    })

    return array;
    
}

var arr = [
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'A', 'B', 'C'];

shuffle(arr);  // Let's randomize it first or our next function has nothing to do! :)
shuffleSort(arr); // Magic!

/* Check results visually */
console.log(arr.join(" "));
        
/* Another check */
arr.forEach((el, index) => {
    if (arr[index] == arr[index + 1]) {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(el);
        window.alert('duplicates!');  // <-- This will never happen :)
    }
})
```